# How do i find dynamic average for not the 20 input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, average

How do i find dynamic average for not the 20 input boxes with ".num" class but even just five out of 20. I have done it as below but it won't work

```
$.fn.sumValues = function() {
        var sum = 0; 
        this.each(function() {
            if ( $(this).is(':input') ) {
                var val = $(this).val();
            } else {
                var val = $(this).text();
            }
            sum += parseFloat( ('0' + val).replace(/[^0-9-\.]/g, ''), 10 );
        });
        return sum.toFixed(2);
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input.price').bind('keyup', function() {
            $('span.total').html( $('input.price').sumValues()/$('.num').length );
        });
    });
```

Comment: You might want to make your question clearer. Specifically your bit "*or not the 20 input boxes with ".num" class but even just five out of 20*", and about why your current script doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: I have 20 input html texboxes, using the function above, i sum dynamically as i add values and divide by 20 to find the average. I would like to dynamically find the sum and the average by counting the number of input boxes with some value greater 0. That by not imputing all the 20. find the sum and average by the number of input box greater than 0